# Putting up scach before walls of sukkah

Tags: halacha, sukkah, architecture-design, schach

If one puts up the scach of the sukkah before building the walls then the sukkah is pasul ([See Rama OC Siman 635 Sif 1.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40432&st=&pgnum=320)) If however a tefach of a wall is put up next to the scach (somach to the scach) before the scach is put up then the Rema says it's permitted to add the scach afterwards then finish off the walls. 
What about if the tefach of the wall was put at the bottom of where the sukkah would be. Do we say "gud asik" in this case and look at it as if the tefach is "somach" (next) to where the scach is?

Comment: The rama doesn't say it's pasul, only not to do it. The achronim argue if it is pasul bedieved.

Comment: @DoubleAA fair enough the M"B brings the Bach as the machshir however many achronim are cholek (See Sharei Tzion.) Al col panim the Rema definitely says "don't do it".

Comment: Perhaps the answer is simple that we don't say gud asik unless the wall is 10 tefachim high however this I still need to find the makor for.

Comment: How else would you build a _gud asik_ suka? Build and break the walls?

Comment: Is a tefach wall a chatzitzah d'minkara?

Comment: @DonielF How would that affect the question? The Rema held that if there is a tefach somach to the scach then it helps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dirshu Mishna Berura quotes R' Elyashiv ZT"L that even  if the tefach is on the ground the Succah is kosher. (mishna Berura 635 s"k 11 #8)

Comment: Thanks for the source-citing answer, Yonah, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you stick around and enjoy [the site](/tour).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Yonah. I will need to go find the sefer in a local shul and look it up inside. However until then maybe you can tell us if there is any reasoning provided there or is it just a statement in the name of R' Eliyashuv that it would be good (without any reason given?)