# Can one use a modified palapa built on a pier as his Succah?

Tags: halacha, sukkah

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palapa_(Mexico)) for a description and picture of a palapa (Aka "tiki hut") built on a pier.

Assume that one puts strong curtains on three sides and ties them down firmly to the side poles so that a normal wind doesn't blow them around, and that the *schach* is kosher.  ([This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95360/472) addresses non-flat roofs.)

Are you allowed to build a succah on a dock like this which is immediately above the water? Is there any rule that says that the succah must be on "firm ground"? Here, waves will rock the dock around a bit.

Comment: About a different kind of slant-roofed _suka_: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10637

Comment: Note there could be practical issues with most of these http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21949/759

Answer (score 4):

Note that since one can build a succa on a boat, the pier should also be allowable. (logic only) 
Maseches Sukka Perek 2 Mishna 3

> If one builds his sukkah on the top of a wagon or on the deck of a
>   ship, it is valid, and they may go up into it on a festival day.

Of course the gemoro on daf 23a of masechet succah points out that this is the subject of a machlokes between Rabbi Akivah and Rabban Gamliel. Rabbi Akivah says that as long as it can withstand a regular land wind, it is kosher. Rabban Gamliel holds that it must withstand a regular sea wind which is stronger. However, even according to Rabban Gamliel, such a sturdy succah would be kosher. The only machlokes is the strength of the wind that must be withstood.

Note that we see examples of a succah built on a boat as shown below.

[Succa on a boat](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/2335069/jewish/7-of-the-Worlds-Most-Interesting-Sukkahs.htm)

> The Sukkah Boat in Venice
>
> Sukkot has a strong connection to the messianic era, of which it is
>   written, “The world will be filled with knowledge of G‑d like water
>   covers the sea.” How apropos that Venice has its very own sukkah boat.
>   Jewish law permits building a sukkah on a boat, a wagon, or even a
>   camel (on chol hamoed), which brings us to the next entry . . .